# Weird issue with concatenate variables

Tags: php

I am a weird issue regarding my class property here

I have the following:

```
$this->tableData = '<table>';

$this->tableData .= $string;

echo $this->tableData   => output <table>
```

I want to concatenate more string to my `$this->tableData` but it seems like nothing is added.

I know $string is not `null` and contains characters

Did I do something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine though. Do you have more information? What is your string you try to add?

Comment: What is the output that you obtain?

Comment: Advance apologies for this but are you sure `$string` has content?

Comment: `var_dump($this->tableData, $string);`

Comment: What is the output of: `$this->tableData = '<table>'.$string; echo $this->tableData;`?

Comment: Are you looking in the HTML source code or the rendered result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if your string is not null you should use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` functions.

Example:

```
$this->tableData = '<table>';
echo "Dumping tableData: " . var_dump($this->tableData);

$this->tableData .= $string;
echo "Dumping tableData 2: " . var_dump($this->tableData);
echo "Dumping string: " . var_dump($string);
```

That way you will see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable $string containing a HTML tag, something like <p></p> or else ?
This could be "hidden" if you print_r it inside a browser.